# Java: compare two numbers directly (a < b) vs by subtracting (a-b < 0)

Tags: java, performance, compare, coding-style

In the books and others code, I can see sometimes

```
if (a-b < 0) ...
```

instead of just simple and better readable

```
if (a < b) ...
```

What is the reason for that?
Is there any performance gain? Or this is just a personal style of coding?...

PS Made the quick naive test with jmh and didn't find any performance gain:

```
@Fork(value = 1)
@Warmup(time = 1)
@Measurement(time = 1)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class Main {

  private long a,b;

  @Setup(value = Level.Invocation)
  public void setup(){
    a = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
    b = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void directCompare(Blackhole bh) {
    bh.consume(a < b);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void substractCompare(Blackhole bh) {
    bh.consume(a - b < 0);
  }

Benchmark              Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
Main.directCompare     avgt    5  27.718 ± 2.778  ns/op
Main.substractCompare  avgt    5  27.055 ± 0.707  ns/op
```

Comment: In optimized raw ASM it makes no difference, but on the JVM (in interpretation mode) it would likely be slower.

Comment: Also be aware that `a - b` can be subject to integer overflow.

Comment: Be careful with `a - b < 0` since `a - b` can cause *integer overflow*

Comment: People write crap code, even authors (sometimes *especially* authors). As you appear to be doing, take everything you read with a pinch of salt. Don't necessarily assume that everything other people do is totally justifiable and rational. Because humans aren't.

Comment: @apangin Yep, I saw it and it should exclude `Math.round(Math.random()*100)` from measurements: "WARNING #1:  Since we have to subtract the setup/teardown costs from the benchmark time...` Nevertheless the results are definitely affected by that level of invocation, but I hope it's affected equally for both benchmarks. And as far as we're interesting in relative results, the exact "nanoseconds" doesn't really matter...